# Creating Multiple File Directories

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have a program that takes a file that points to a folder somewhere. I need to then make two separate directories. For example, say I have a file base that points to folder `Base`. I would then want to create two directories dir1 and dir2.

I know that you do the following:

```
//Called in constructor
File base = new File (baseFileLocString);

//Make directories
File dir1 = new File (base.getAbsoluteFilePate() + "/dir1");
dir1.mkdir();

File dir2 = new File (base.getAbsoluteFilePate() + "/dir2");
dir2.mkdir();
```

I do not like this way though. Ideally I could use `base` and make the directories without having to create new `Files`. I feel like there should be a more efficient way to do this. Is that the case or no?

Comment: But a directory is a type of file--what's the issue? I mean, you could wrap it up in a utility method or use an existing one like from Apache Commons, but...

Comment: I agreed with @DaveNewton. Plus you should use new File(base, "dir1"). Check the javadoc.

Comment: I guess there is no real deal here. I just thought it was a bit ugly looking and less than ideal. Maybe this is more semantics than anything.

It just seems wasteful to have to create those two extra `File` objects.

Comment: I don't see what the problem with `new File(base, "dir1").mkdir()` is, I guess.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I think a better way to word the question would be: "Is there a way to make these directories with only one `File` object?

Comment: But it's two files... Again, I don't see what the problem is. Even if you wrap it up or use somebody else's utility, I'm pretty sure it's still going to do essentially the same thing. What's your specific issue?

Comment: @PepperedLemons Answering you last question: no, there is no way to do that in java.

Comment: Hmm.. I may be over thinking this. I guess I really don't have a problem. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative

```
Files.createDirectory(Paths.get(base.getAbsoluteFilePath(), "dir1"));
```

besides it is better than File.mkdir because if something goes wrong mkdir returns false without expalnation and createDirectory throws an exception which explains what happened

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`File dir1 = new File (base.getAbsoluteFilePath() + "/dir1");`

You could use

`File dir1 = new File (base, "dir1");`

Looks better, but the performance will stay the same